# Trainable USE-lite-based classifier with SentencePiece input

Tags: tensorflow, language-model

I have heard that it is possible to use the pretrained Universal Sentence Encoder (USE) (neural language model) from TF-hub as part of a trainable model, e.g. a sentence classifier.  Some versions of USE rely on SentencePiece sub-word tokenizer, which I also need.  There are minimal instructions online for how to do this.

Here is how to use USE-lite with SentencePiece:
-  https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-lite/2

Here is how to train a classifier based on a pretrained USE model:
-  http://hunterheidenreich.com/blog/google-universal-sentence-encoder-in-keras/
-  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gnz1CUzb5qo

And here is how to measure sentence similarity using both USE-lite and SentencePiece:
-  https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/blob/master/examples/colab/semantic_similarity_with_tf_hub_universal_encoder_lite.ipynb

I have successfully reproduced the above pieces separately.  I have then tried to combine the above ideas into a single POC that will build a classifier model based on USE-lite and SentencePiece, but I cannot see how to do it.  I am currently stuck on the part where I modify the trainable classifier's first layer(s).  I have tried to make it accept either (1) SentencePiece token IDs (in which I tokenize the text outide of the Tensorflow graph) or (2) raw text (using SentencePiece as an Op inside the Tensorflow graph).  After that point, it should feed tokenized text forward into the USE-lite model, either in a lambda or in some other way.  Finally, the output of USE-lite should be fed into a dense layer (or two?) ending in softmax for computing class probabilities.

I am relatively new to Tensorflow.  I imagine that the above sources would be sufficient for a more experienced Tensorflow developer to merge and make work for my use-case.  Let me know if you can provide any pointers.  Thanks.

Comment: The solution to this problem seems to be to wait for a better version of USE in Tensorflow-Hub.  Multilingual USE is much easier to use.  It allowed me to input plain text instead of SentencePiece IDs, as it does the SentencePiece encoding for me in the TF graph.  It was relatively easy to join the USE model to a fully connected network.  The only problem was, there is a bug in the USE layer in TF-hub that prevents me from saving a model if I train the USE weights.  I can only save the model if I do not train the USE weights.  So I will wait for someone to debug these models.

Comment: A text classifier was made by Google using the Universal Sentence Encoder lite,
Here is the code link:
https://github.com/conversationai/conversationai-models/tree/master/experiments/tf_trainer/tf_hub_tfjs

Ref Also :  https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/tfjs-model/toxicity/1/default/1

@tpacker